# Shared Library Can't Be Loaded by Lampp

Tags: c++, linux, xampp

I'm running into a strange problem on RHEL server.
I'm running `./lampp start`, trying to run xampp service, but then I got a bunch of errors indicating that it failed to load shared library :

```
netstat: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: error while loading shared libraries: libdl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/opt/lampp/bin/gettext: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/opt/lampp/bin/gettext: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
XAMPP: netstat: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: error while loading shared libraries: libdl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: error while loading shared libraries: libdl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/opt/lampp/bin/gettext: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/opt/lampp/bin/gettext: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have checked and those libraries exist in /usr/lib64

```
[root@xxxxxuserlib64]# cd /usr/lib64
[root@xxxxxuserlib64]# ls -al |grep libc.so
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root      253 May 19  2020 libc.so
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       12 Sep  3 18:01 libc.so.6 -> libc-2.17.so
```

I have tried running ldconfig

```
[root@xxxxxuserlib64]# ldconfig -v | grep libc
ldconfig: Path `/lib' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/lib64' given more than once
ldconfig: Can't stat /libx32: No such file or directory
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib64' given more than once
ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/libx32: No such file or directory
        libcommon.so.9.3 -> libcommon.so.9.3.1
        libcryptsetup.so.12 -> libcryptsetup.so.12.3.0
        libcupscgi.so.1 -> libcupscgi.so.1
        libcupsmime.so.1 -> libcupsmime.so.1
        libcupsimage.so.2 -> libcupsimage.so.2
        libcidn.so.1 -> libcidn-2.17.so
        libcupsppdc.so.1 -> libcupsppdc.so.1
        libcups.so.2 -> libcups.so.2
        libcrack.so.2 -> libcrack.so.2.9.0
        libcroco-0.6.so.3 -> libcroco-0.6.so.3.0.1
        libcrypto.so.10 -> libcrypto.so.1.0.2k
        libcpupower.so.0 -> libcpupower.so.0.0.0
        libcairo-script-interpreter.so.2 -> libcairo-script-interpreter.so.2.11512.0
        libcap.so.2 -> libcap.so.2.22
        libcgroup.so.1 -> libcgroup.so.1.0.41
        libcairo.so.2 -> libcairo.so.2.11512.0
        libcollection.so.2 -> libcollection.so.2.1.1
        libc.so.6 -> libc-2.17.so
        libcap-ng.so.0 -> libcap-ng.so.0.0.0
        libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1
        libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.3.0
        libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.17.so
        libcryptsetup.so.4 -> libcryptsetup.so.4.7.0
```

and it seems fine, the libc is loaded.

I tried to add export LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable in .bashrc

```
[root@xxxxxxuserlib64]# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib:/usr/lib64
[root@xxxxxxuser lib64]#
```

Still, no avail, same problem. Lastly I tried to add libc into the sampe directory as gettext, but still, I got an error. By now I have exhausted my options. How can I solve this?

Comment: The issue is with netstat not being able to load libraries. Could it be that the netstat binary is compiled for 32-bits, but you are running it on a system with only 64-bit libraries installed?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error occured because I upgraded my Red Hat server to RHEL 7.9, and Lampp happened to have the following flag set :

```
export LD_ASSUME_KERNEL=2.2.5
```

Which incompatible with the new kernel after the update which is of version 3.10.0.

So I just commented out the line. Not sure if that's the proper way to handle it, but at least it gets the service up and running. I'll still let the question open in case anyone have a better way of handling such case.